# A-frame video doesn't appear in safari

Tags: ios, video, safari, aframe

I’m working with **A-frame** and **arjs** and I did a location based web app

it’s working fine on android the issue is on IOS **safari** exactly

the **video doesn’t show up** even the first frame doesn’t appear

the video src attribute is set with js

the a-entity “gps-entity-place” attribute is set also with js

```
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;">

        <a-assets>
            <img id="alpha" src="mask.png">
            <video id="vid" autoplay playsinline webkit-playsinline muted loop="true"></video>
        </a-assets>

        <a-entity id="entityToShow" position="0 50 0" rotation="0 0 0">

            <!-- Textured plane parallel to trex. -->
            <a-plane id="videoPlane" material="shader:grid-glitch; map: #vid; map2: #alpha ; myOpacity : 0.5" height="6"
                width="3.4" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1" look-at="#camera">
            </a-plane>

        </a-entity>

        <a-camera id="camera" gps-camera look-controls-enabled='false' arjs-look-controls='smoothingFactor: 0.1'
            rotation-reader>
        </a-camera>

    </a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how i fixed the problem :
I removed the JS setting for the video src attribute